# svg positionning on window resize after changing scale / zoom with react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I am trying to resize and scale an svg embedded in a div container. My goal is to change te svg through props as a React component. 
You can look at the code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1rv54qw513) .

I made the svg circle keep its position on window resize using viewbox and matrix transform. And I can zoom on the circle accordingly on mouse wheel. For the zoom I set the width and height of the parent container in the component state on the window resize event.

But when I zoomed before changing window resize, the circle doesn't keep its position.

**Do you have any idea how to make my coordinates independant from the zoom scale ?**

I have tried many things, like calculating a new width and height with each time the scale change (and so the viewbox), but it didn't work ...

Also if you know any good resources to forward me to on manipulating svg in a canvas like, it would be also very helpful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I can see your problem, I have refactor your code and make it work,you can check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pj07npzjwx).
The problem is that as you scale the svg the center point also get scaled.What you need to do is to apply the inverse of the scale to the center to position the circle in the div center.Take a look at the calculatePoisition method.
I have done it in the

Comment: It's exactly what I was searching for. Very clean answer ! Thanks !!

Comment: Now if you had both presented your code here in the question and answer, others could see what you are talking about. Please compare what [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) has to say about helping others reproduce the problem.

Comment: I understand but the code is quite large, I have put a link in my answer to a codesandbox ,https://codesandbox.io/s/pj07npzjwx .